# No space left on device - although there is plenty of space and inodes

Tags: linux, usb, encryption, ntfs, truecrypt

I have a USB disk with truecrypt volume for backup.
This truecrypt volume occupies almost the whole USB disk.
USB disk and the truecrypt volume have both NTFS format.

When I tried to copy a directory containing about 165MB data and 40000 files into the truecrypt volume I got following errors

Cannot create file /media/truecrypt10/filename - No space left on device

However, it seems that there are space and inodes. This situation is just after copy failure:

```
[q@localhost truecrypt10]$ df -H 
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdb2             3.1T  3.1T  187M 100% /media/Backup_C2
/dev/loop0            3.1T  2.6T  456G  85% /media/truecrypt10

[q@localhost truecrypt10]$ df -i
Filesystem              Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdb2               111060      48    111012    1% /media/Backup_C2
/dev/loop0           446628656 1653104 444975552    1% /media/truecrypt10
```

I tried this couple of time, also closed the truecrypt volume and reattached USB disk and reopened the truecrypt volume but copy fails.

As a workaround I tar-zipped the whole directory into the truecrypt volume without a problem.

After this I attached the USB disk into Win7 box, run chkdsk -f and it found no errors in it.

```
CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  1653104 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  884 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  120 EA records processed.
  0 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
  2008216 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
  1653104 file SDs/SIDs processed.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  177556 data files processed.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

   2861055 MB total disk space.
   2424106 MB in 1442224 files.
    661168 KB in 177558 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1811235 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 444963760 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 732430271 total allocation units on disk.
 111240940 allocation units available on disk.
```

What is the reason for copy failure and how to overcome it? Is it an error or somekind of mismatch between linux and NTFS?

My Linux is Centos6.7 Linux 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64

EDIT: 
Additional testing showed that copying the same 165MB directory than above from Win7 to the same USB disk / same truecrypt volume succeeds without any errors.

Comment: Did or can you try it on a Windows PC?

Comment: Yes, copying from win succeeded. See the EDIT.

Comment: Can it have something to do with the filesystem?